# How to quickly calculate this expression?

Tags: arithmetic

What is the best and quickest way to calculate this expression without writing a program or using a calculator?:

> $1+2-3+4+5-6+7+8-9+10\cdots+100$

Comment: Do you mean $0+3+6+9+\cdots+96+100$?

Comment: @XanderHenderson It's not a duplicate.

Comment: @zython Signs. Don't miss them.

Comment: Oi!  I missed the minus signs... oops.

Comment: it's basically the difference of sums of multiples of finite arithmetic progressions. one with distance 1 and start 1 and one with distance 3 and start 3 times 2. the classical result still helps out to some extent.

Answer (score 3):

You are calculating the sum of all non multiples of $3$ from which you are substracting the multiples of $3$, enabling the formal representation :

$$ \sum_{0 \leq k \leq 33} (-(3k) + (3k+1) +(3k+2))-101 = \sum_{k=0}^{33} (3k +3) -101$$

$$ = \frac{((3\times33+3)+(3\times0+3))34}{2}-101$$

$$ = 17 \times 105 -101$$

$$ = 1684$$

Comment: $1684$, not $1648$

Comment: Indeed, it's just a simple computation error at the end: $17 \times 105 - 101 =  1684$.  Edited.  Happens to us all.  Wyllich's work, and logic, is in fact correct; my edit was to simply correct the juxtaposition of "48" with "84"

Answer (score 1):

If you consider the section of the sum around each multiple of $3$, for example:

$$14-15+16 = 15-15+15 = 15$$

or  in general

$$(k-1)-k+(k+1) = k$$

you can see that the sum required is the initial $1$ and then the multiples of $3$:

$$1+\sum_{k=1}^{33} 3k = 1+ 3\sum_{k=1}^{33} k  = 1+3\cdot 33\cdot34/2 = 1+99\cdot 17 = 1684$$

Answer (score 1):

If we add and subtract multiples of three, this can be written as
$$ \sum_{k=1}^{100}k-2 \sum_{k=1}^{33} 3k=50*101-6*33*17=1684$$

Answer (score 1):

$$\sum _{k=1}^{100} k-2 \sum _{k=1}^{\left\lfloor \frac{100}{3}\right\rfloor } 3 k=\frac{100 (1+100)}{2}-3 \left\lfloor \frac{100}{3}\right\rfloor  \left(\left\lfloor \frac{100}{3}\right\rfloor +1\right)=1684$$

Answer (score 0):

If we rearrange the sum to:
$$1 + 2 + 3 + 4 + 5 + 6 \ ... \ + 100 -2(3 + 6 + 9 + \ ... \ + 99)$$

This is the same as the sum of all of the natural numbers up to and including $100$, then subtract $3(2)$ times the sum of all natural numbers up to and including $33$ to get it to become $1 + 2 - 3 + 4 + 5 - 6 + \ ... \ $, i.e.:

$$\frac{100(99)}{2} -6\frac{33(32)}{2} = 1683$$

Then we have to add $1$, because that also gets removed from when we subtract the sum with 33 terms, so the final answer is $1684$.

Where sum of the natural numbers up to and including $n$ is $\frac{n(n+1)}{2}$

Answer (score 0):

First, we can regroup the terms, giving us something a little easier to work with:
\begin{align}
&1 + 2 - 3 + 4 + 5 - 6 + 7 + 8 - 9 + \dotsb + 100 \\
&\qquad= (1 + 4 + \dotsb + 100) + (2 + 5 + \dotsb + 98) - (3 + 6 + \dotsb + 99)
\end{align}
Notice that the first block consists of numbers of the form $3k+1$, with $k$ running from 0 to 33 (since $100 = 33k+1$).  Thus the first term looks like
$$ 1 + 4 + 7 + \dotsb + 100 = \sum_{k=0}^{33} 3k+1.$$
Similarly, we can rewrite the second and third terms to get
\begin{align}
&(1 + 4 + \dotsb + 100) + (2 + 5 + \dotsb + 98) - (3 + 6 + \dotsb + 99) \\
&\qquad= \sum_{k=0}^{33} (3k+1) + \sum_{k=0}^{32} (3k+2) - \sum_{k=0}^{33} 3k \\
&\qquad= \left( 34 + 3\sum_{k=0}^{33} k \right) + \left( 66 + 3\sum_{k=0}^{32} k \right) - 3\sum_{k=0}^{33} k \\
&\qquad= 34 + 68 + 3\sum_{k=0}^{32} k.
\end{align}
Note that the second sum goes from 0 to 32 (not 33), because we can write $98 = 3\cdot 32 + 2$.  This sum ends up being the one that doesn't cancel with the other two.  To evaluate the sum, we use the well-known result that
$$\sum_{k=0}^{n} k = \frac{n(n+1)}{2}$$
in order to get
$$ 34 + 68 + 3\sum_{k=0}^{32} k
= 102 + 3\cdot\frac{32(32+1)}{2}
= 102 + 1584
= 1684.$$

Answer (score 0):

We can write 1+2-3+4+5-6+7+8-9+10+⋯+95+95-96+97+98-99+100 like this :

0+3+6+9+⋯+93+96+100

now using the formula of finding the arithmetic sum for 0+3+6+9+⋯+93+96

**S**n=n/2(**a**1+**a**n)

we'll have

**S**33=33/2(0+96)=33*48=1584

adding 100 to this we take 1584+100=1684 therefore

1+2-3+4+5-6+7+8-9+10+⋯+95+95-96+97+98-99+100=1684

Answer (score 0):

1) $1+2+3+4+....+100=$

$101 ×50$ $ (n(n+1)/2)$.

2) $3+6+9+ .... 99 =$

$3(1+2+3+4+...+33) =$

$3 × 33×17$.

$1+2-3+4+5-6+...+100=$

$101×50 - 2×3×33×17$.